# Redirecting mobile-desktop versions manually

Tags: javascript, php, mobile, session-variables

I have this code in my homepage

```
<?php
 if(isset($_SESSION['mobile'])){
   if($_SESSION['mobile']==1){
     echo '
         <script>
           if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
             window.location = "mobile/index.php";
           }
         </script>';
   }
 }
 else{
   $_SESSION['mobile']=1;
   echo '
         <script>
           if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
             window.location = "mobile/index.php";
           }
         </script>';
 }
?>
```

and on the mobile version of my website, to get back to the destop version I inserted a link to this almost empty "redirect.php" page

```
<?php 
  $_SESSION['mobile']=0; 
  header("location: ../index.php");
  exit;
?>
```

but I am not getting the desired behavior: once I enter the website with my mobile, I am correctly redirected to the mobile version, but once I click on the link to get the desktop version, I loop back into the mobile version. What am I missing?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Remember to call `session_start()` function before using sessions.

Better use this to reduce code:

```
<?php session_start();

if (isset($_GET["desktop"])) {

    // DESKTOP
    $_SESSION["mobile"] = 0;
    ...

} else {

    // MOBILE
    if (!isset($_SESSION["mobile"])) { $_SESSION["mobile"] = 1; }
    if ($_SESSION["mobile"] == 1){ echo '<script>...</script>'; }
    ...

}
?>
```

And link to the homepage with `?desktop=1` to switch to the desktop version.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I would like to understand why my code does not work! :)

Comment: I tried your solution, and it looks like my phone (Nexus 4 with Android 4.4.4) does not work with $_SESSION variables. In fact, it "forgets" the $_SESSION['mobile']=0 once I change password in the desktop version on my Nexus, and it goes back to the mobile version!

Comment: @Sfrow Are you calling `session_start()` function before using sessions?

Comment: Yep! I call it at each page on my site!

Comment: Can be you have accidental whitespace or other output before `session_start()`. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` before `session_start()` to see if there any warning.

Comment: I did it, and it does not give me any error of any kind. :(

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current code - You should have a separate session var that tell you that the user has manually reqeusted control.

```
<?php
if(!$_SESSION['manuall_overide'])
 if(isset($_SESSION['mobile'])){
   if($_SESSION['mobile']==1){
     echo '
         <script>
           if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
             window.location = "mobile/index.php";
           }
         </script>';
   }
 }
 else{
   $_SESSION['mobile']=1;
   echo '
         <script>
           if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
             window.location = "mobile/index.php";
           }
         </script>';
 }
}
?>

<?php 
  $_SESSION['manuall_overide']=1; 
  header("location: ../index.php");
  exit;
?>
```

Comment: I do not see why this should work and mine no. Why a separate session var? In the end, if $_SESSION is not set it gets to the else, if it is set to one, it gets to the nested if, if zero, it gets into the first if and does nothing... why does not it work?